# How to switch between Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse

I have installed IBM Mobilefirst Platform studio into eclipse from Eclipse Marketplace. It is working fine. The eclipse user interface have changed. After that, I installed JBoss Tools into eclipse from Marketplace. After restarted eclipse, the UI is changed to JBoss tools and I find no where to switch back the UI for Mobilefirst platform studio.

Is it I have to uninstall JBoss Tools first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely seeing different *Perspectives* in Eclipse, one contributed by Mobilefirst and another contributed by JBoss Tools. Here's an overview of Eclipse Perspectives from [the help pages](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-4.htm):

> Each Workbench window contains one or more perspectives. A perspective defines the initial set and layout of views in the Workbench window. Within the window, each perspective shares the same set of editors. Each perspective provides a set of functionality aimed at accomplishing a specific type of task or works with specific types of resources. For example, the Java perspective combines views that you would commonly use while editing Java source files, while the Debug perspective contains the views that you would use while debugging Java programs. As you work in the Workbench, you will probably switch perspectives frequently.
>
> Perspectives control what appears in certain menus and toolbars. They define visible action sets, which you can change to customize a perspective. You can save a perspective that you build in this manner, making your own custom perspective that you can open again later.

Check out that link, there is a lot more information about using perspectives. Basically, you can easily switch between the different perspectives in the UI. They can usually co-exist peacefully, so there's no need to uninstall anything. Just familiarize yourself with the Eclipse UI concepts.